# How to use an associative array value for calculation in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I am performing a calculation using the user input and associative arrays. Below is my PHP code

```
$class          = $_POST['class'];
$size           = $_POST['size'];
$gasket         = $_POST['gasket'];
$connection     = $_POST['connection'];

$flange150 = array( 
    array( flangesize  => 0.5,      /* Inches */
        flangeclass => 150,
        flangethick => 0.38,     /* Inches */
        boltdia     => 0.5,      /* Inches */
        totalbolt   => 4
    ),
    array( flangesize  => 0.75,     /* Inches */
            flangeclass => 150,
            flangethick => 0.44,     /* Inches */
            boltdia     => 0.5,      /* Inches */
            totalbolt   => 4
    ),

);
```

the user input size is stored in a variable $size and using this variable i need to select the array which has the same value as the user input (flangesize in array). Then from that array I must take the value of flangethick for my calculation. But i dont know how to perform this. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach something like this

```
$flangethick = "";
foreach ($flange150 as $key =>$val) {
      if ($val['flangesize'] == $_POST['size']) { 
          $flangethick = $val['flangethick'];
      }
}
echo $flangethick;
```

So, this will have your value

Comment: @Dhanasekaran Don't forget to use `break;` as I did in my answer. Without it you'll iterate through all items even if you already found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is:

```
$flangethick = 0;
foreach ($flange150 as $item) {
   if ($item['flangesize'] == $size) {
       $flangethick = $item['flangethick'];
       break;
   }
}
```

And if you're using arrays, don't forget to use `'` or `"` in indexes.